# DelegateCommand vs RoutedCommand and gestures - WPF

Tags: wpf, prism, routed-commands, delegatecommand

is there anyway for DelegateCommand's to support gestures when building a composite WPF app?  I'm trying to create a command used by a MenuItem and also a Button, which can be accessed through a keyboard shortcut, but which sits inside a class in a separate assembly.

I can use a RoutedCommand, but I want to minimise any code-behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [InputBindingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbindingcollection.aspx) to map gestures with ICommand.